# Change HTTP Host-Header of a generated Service Reference call from WSDL

Tags: c#, http, wcf, wsdl, endpoint

I have in my computer a WSDL link to my local EndPoint. I have generated the Service reference and can access everything fine when i do it locally i.e. *http://localhost/ApplicationHost/EndPoint*

If I use another computer(in the network) the request is done via IP i.e. *Http://15.5.20.10/ApplicationHost/EndPoint* but this will respond a 400 Bad request.

Changing the Host of the request to "localhost" (as tested on firefox and android) works fine.

[image]

The image has  the perfect functional case. The Address has the IP and the host is "localhost" but I cant manage to replicate this in c#.

How can I do the same using C# and the Service reference? I have tried so far a lot of solutions that ADDS a http header but none of them will acctually change a existing one: i.e [Adding http headers to a Service Reference service method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509053/adding-http-headers-to-a-service-reference-service-method) or [How to add a custom HTTP header to every WCF call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-http-header-to-every-wcf-call) or [how to modify http header of request; web reference in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238503/how-to-modify-http-header-of-request-web-reference-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

On the client-side, we can modify the header through IClientMessageInspector,here is a demo:

```
   public class ClientMessageLogger : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        { 
        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            HttpRequestMessageProperty header;
            if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name))
            {
                header = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
            }
            else
            {
                header = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, header);
            }

            header.Headers["Host"] = "localhost";
            return null;
        }
    }
```

ClientMessageLogger implements the IClientMessageInspector interface, and I modify its request header before the client post a request.

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class CustContractBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior, IContractBehaviorAttribute, IOperationBehavior
    {
        public Type TargetContract => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new ClientMessageLogger());
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
        {

        }

        public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

We add the ClientMessageLogger to the client's behavior.

```
    [CustContractBehavior]
    public interface IService
    {...}
```

Finally, we add this behavior to the interface of the service.

Comment: This does not work for me, the host header is still the same when the request is actually send.